# Issues installing Ubuntu Server 16.04 onto Dell Optiplex 960

Tags: server, system-installation, 16.04, dell

Issues installing Ubuntu Server 14 and 16 onto Dell OptiPlex 960.

I've installed Ubuntu Server 12 and 14 many times and 16 a few times on old Dell OptiPlex 755s, but I have a few 960s collecting dust. Which the 960s have much better CPUs and more RAM.

My issue with OptiPlex 960s is this: I can boot to disc, where you are asked what language. I choose English. Then I choose install Ubuntu Server. Disc light flashes then goes black and screen goes black. No response from any key on the keyboard. Forcing me to reboot.

I've tried nomodeset with no success.

I've tried vga=normal fb=false with no success.

I've tried vga=normal with no success

I've tried turning off TPM in BIOS with no success.

I've tried completely disabling TPM in BIOS with no succeses.

I've tried Ubuntu Server 12 and 14 and 16 with above variations with no success.

I've tried hooking up a second monitor to the display port with no success.

I've tried with internet and without internet with no success.

I've tried installing minimal system with no success.

It always goes to a black screen after the main install menu.

I'm about to throw in the towel, again. Any suggestions will greatly help. I'm not at all afraid of terminal commands. This has been an ongoing challenge for a few months now, I was praying Ubuntu Server 16.04 would solve the issue.

UPDATE:

Tried to install Ubuntu Server 16.04 which worked on an old OptiPlex 330, no issues, no hiccups.

Still no success with every OptiPlex 960 I try.

When its at the black screen, there is no activity lights on the Optical drive, nor on the HDD, nor the Ethernet, only a solid light indicating power.

I let it hang at the black screen for hours upon hours with no change, no success, requiring a reboot.

I was able to install Debian using a Net Installer iso. So I'm confused as to why Ubuntu Server wont install.

Comment: And it happens on every 960 you try?

Comment: I'm also assuming it's not something really simple, like, your CD drive or disk is damaged?  Out of curiosity, have you tried installing from a pendrive?  Also curious to know if you have tried booting into a livecd like Lubuntu.

Comment: Can't use a pendrive (usb jump drive/flash drive) for security purposes on site. I have burned multiple discs (10+) and I check disc each time before proceeding. I have used an internal optical drive, and an external USB optical drive. All yielding the same results. I was able to make the kernel panic a good too many times, throughout this process. And yes happens on multiple 960s not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Change the RAID settings in the BIOS to Legacy and it should work.  I just installed 16.04.3 to an optiplex 960.